# Presto How to Implement Authentication for only specific users

Tags: security, authentication, presto

can someone help me with some insight about this theme.

I have Presto installed in my Hadoop cluster and I have not authentication configured for inside the cluster, but i want to give access from outside of cluster and want to configure authentication only for that type of access.

Anyone know any solution?

I allready tried with the hadoop impersonation configurations but don't solve the problem.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Specifically what type of authentication are you looking for? e.g. LDAP, Kerberos. Did you see these docs to get started:
https://prestodb.io/docs/current/security.html